# Is it possible to do > or < operators in angular HTML?

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to do some dynamic color changes based on a value in HTML. I want it to do this but in HTML using angular plugins.

```
if(ClassyAverage >50 class = red)
else if(ClassyAverage >40 class = orange)
else(class = green)
```

I have some CSS values that I can get the color from as well

```
.red{
  color: #f00;
} 

.green {
   color: #0f0;
}

.orange{
  color: orange;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [possible to do simple calculation with html/css, but without javascript, or backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056931/possible-to-do-simple-calculation-with-html-css-but-without-javascript-or-back)

Comment: You're looking for [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) and/or [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) wherein something like `[ngStyle]="{'color': needsColor ? 'red' : 'transparent'}"` is quick and easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `[ngClass]="{'red':ClassyAverage>50,'orange':ClassyAverage>40}"`
and use your default `class` as green.

`[ngClass]` is very useful when you want to add css classes depending on the variables in the component.

Comment: Hey, I wish I could say that it worked... but it still won't change color based on value. it just gives black text. I have CSS classes called red and orange, but they never get called no matter the value of ClassyAverage

Comment: I don't see a problem for it not to work, can you provide the code using stackblitz link so that i can check

Comment: Yeah no problem, but there are some files that I won't be able to put into stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5hjdkv. Basically what my app is doing is getting data from a python program called "FakeData". The fake data is loaded into classyaverage and classyaverage just displays on the screen updating every so often. I used a Typescript to changer the colors with ngStyle, but it was and dynamic nor simplistic as I need it to be. But when I added the ngClass in it just change the text color black and left it at that no matter the Value that Classyavergae was at.

Comment: Your app on stackblitz is not working, just upload the part you have problem with

Comment: your variable name is `Classyaverage` not `ClassyAverage` Use the correct name it will work.